# custom env file names for vuejs modes beside dev and prod?

Tags: vue.js

I have a `vue.js` app, and it is using two files named `dev.env.js` and `prod.env.js` to read environment variables and configure the app.
the `dev.env.js` is currently configured with data that our frontend developers are using.
I need to make some adjustments on my own and need another env file.

I have created a file named `ninja.env.js` next to the other files in `config/` which contains:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
    NODE_ENV: '"development"',
    SERVER_PATH: '"localhost:8560"',
    SOCKET_PATH: '"localhost:8561/map"'
}
```

but there is no way to run this.
I have tried:

```
$ npm run ninja    
>>> npm ERR! missing script: ninja


$ npm run dev --mode ninja
>>> Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                            11:12:02 AM

This dependency was not found:

* ninja in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ninja

To install it, you can run: npm install --save ninja
```

so, is there a way to add multiple environment files?

Comment: In what context is this used? vue-cli? What routines include the config files in `/config` ?

Comment: @madflow we have created the app using the command `vue init webpack my-project` and we haven't changed this `config/` folder at all. there were 3-4 lines which our frontend developers were commenting and uncommenting to change their environments. I just want to clean this pattern of setting URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as mentioned in [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code), basically you can add different modes like this:
`.env.[MODE_NAME]`
And they you can run it like:
`vue-cli-service build --mode [MODE_NAME]`